# Why an app deployed to k8s with ArgoCD has Application and Ingress stuck in "Progressing" state?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, wsl-2, argocd, kind

I have Docker running in WSL2 (no Docker Desktop in Windows, just docker engine within WSL), and a Kubernetes cluster created with kinD. Inside this cluster, there's an ArgoCD server.

I have built a little demo app which runs in port 8083, and returns just a "Hello, World" message when hitting localhost:8083.

I have deployed the app to my ArgoCD, using the following commands and yaml scripts:

**demo-app-chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: demo-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  source:
    path: manifests
    repoURL: (the github repo for the yaml scripts)
    targetRevision: HEAD
  destination:
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    namespace: default # kube-system
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
```

**yaml scripts in repo:**

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: (path to docker image in docker hub)
        name: demo-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8083
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8083
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8083
  selector:
    app: demo-app
  type: NodePort
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kind.cluster.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: demo-app-service
            port:
              number: 8083
```

The app is deployed, and Service, Deployment and Pods have Sync and Health status OK. Application and Ingress resources have Sync status OK, but the Health is stuck in "Progressing".
[Screenshot of the app in ArgoCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maavW.png)

I have tried getting the cluster IP like this:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                                         NAMES
03f01542d6e5   kindest/node:v1.27.3   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 127.0.0.1:35235->6443/tcp   my-super-cluster-control-plane
```

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' my-super-cluster-control-plane
172.18.0.2
```

And I added the Cluster IP to the /etc/hosts file in WSL to match the host name in the Ingress configuration:

```
172.18.0.2      kind.cluster.internal
```

But no change in the Application/Ingress status.

This is also the result I get when getting the services status:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
demo-app-service   NodePort    10.96.110.156   <none>        8083:31707/TCP   43m
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          86m
```

I'm thinking I need to do some route mapping, but don't know how actually do it. Any help will be very much appreciated.

**Update**
When looking at the Ingress details, I see there's no "Address", and only port 80.

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME               CLASS    HOSTS                   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
demo-app-ingress   <none>   kind.cluster.internal             80      8h

$ kubectl describe ingress demo-app-ingress
Name:             demo-app-ingress
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=demo-app
Namespace:        default
Address:
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                   Path  Backends
  ----                   ----  --------
  kind.cluster.internal
                         /   demo-app-service:8083 (10.244.0.2:8083,10.244.0.8:8083)
Annotations:             <none>
Events:                  <none>
```

Comment: Look at the Ingress details, it may have details. Likely the Ingress cannot be "registered" correctly in the Ingress Controller.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. There are no errors in  the Summary view in ArgoCD UI. I have added some details I got from kubectl describe.